# iOS set barbuttonitems to navigation item always have animated

Tags: ios, jquery-animate, uibarbuttonitem

I add the bar button items to the navigation item.

But I found I set the animated NO or YES, the barbuttonitems always have animate from left to right.

How can I cancel the animate on set the bar button items.

My code below:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
 ...
 doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self      action:@selector(barbuttonDoen)];

 ...
 }

 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

 // self.theMenu is using storyboard drag.

 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneBtn, self.theMenu animated:NO];

 }
```

thank you very much.

Comment: you need to set alpha of right bar button instead of set right button.

Comment: How to set the alpha of right bar button and what the relation alpha and animate?thanks

Comment: because if you set right button every time then it will be jerk animation so you need to set alpha.

Comment: Could you teach how to set the alpha on the RightBarButtonItems? thanks.

Comment: as same :     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide and show right button through `alpha` property .

**Show**

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView setAlpha:1.0];
```

**Hide**

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView setAlpha:0.0];
```

**Animation**

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView setAlpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: Hi @KKRocks. I try to set [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView setAlpha:0.0];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneBtn, self.theMenu animated:NO];
But when I run on the keyboardWillShow, the doneBtn and theMenu still show animate from left to right move. I don't known why @@

Comment: I don't want to show the animate when I set the RightBarButtonItems.

Comment: did still use in keyboardWillShow ? self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneBtn, self.theMenu animated:NO];

Comment: It is using when the keyboard show, it will more the doneBtn navbarbuttonitem(so have 2 navbarbuttonitems on the rightbarbuttonitems), the keyboard hide, it will hide the doneBtn on rightbarbuttonitem, show the menu navbarbutton item.

Comment: yes then set both button on viewdidLoad with done button alpha 0 and menu alpha 1. if key board appear then change alpha accroding to that.

Comment: But if the keyboard show , I need the move the menu to doneBtn left(Show Menu,Done) , the keyboard hide, the menu will on the right , not need doneBtn empty space.( show Menu)